# MVC 3 Displaying a dynamic image created in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mschart

I'm trying generate a images/chart in my controller and have that image displayed in an image tag in the view.  In my view, I have

```
<div id="graphcontainer"><a href="#">Close Graph</a><img id="chartImage" alt="" /></div>
```

and in my controller (called EventReport) I have a method called "BuildChart".  My idea was to capture the click event of a button designated as the build report button.  In the click event handler I would want to assign the image's source to something like "/EventReport/BuildChart" to have the image control populated.

Here's what's in the controller

```
public ActionResult BuildChart()
{
    var chart = new Chart
                    {
                        Height = Unit.Pixel(400),
                        Width = Unit.Pixel(600),
                        AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics,
                        BackColor = Color.White
                    };

    // Populate chart here ... 

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    chart.SaveImage(ms);
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

I'm just having problems wiring this up.  Am I on the right track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `src` of your image as link to your action on the click of your button, eg:

using jquery:

```
$('#build-chart').click(function() {
   $('#chartImage').attr('src', '/EventReport/BuildChart');
});
```

and action will be asked for content for image. Probably some 'loading' indicator will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there a 'refresh' or 'load' method that needs to be executed?

Comment: I don't know such in image. Probably you will need to play with browser cahsing, or try to append some random (or not random, report type for example) to your url

Comment: To refresh the chart you need to set another link to `src`